Python web socket client running in Docker
My objective is to run a web socket client in a dockerized python application. It's light weight and only with bare necessities now for testing purposes.
Here is my Python script "client.py":
import websocket
import time


def on_message(ws, message):
    print(f"Message received: {message}")


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(f"Error: {error}")


def on_close(ws):
    print("WebSocket connection closed.")


def on_open(ws):
    print("WebSocket connection opened.")


def run_websocket():
    print("Starting WebSocket connection.")
    websocket_url = "wss://websocket-url"
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
        url=websocket_url,
        on_open=on_open,
        on_message=on_message,
        on_error=on_error,
        on_close=on_close,
    )

    while True:
        try:
            ws.run_forever()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"WebSocket error: {e}")
            time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_websocket()



When I run this client locally, it works like a charm. I can spint it up using `py client.py´ and the client connects to the server (I provide credentials and more information, this is just my lightweight experiment).
However, when I build it to an image using this Dockerfile:

FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -t requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "client.py"]


It doesn't trigger at all. The first log ´Starting WebSocket connection." does not show up, it gets stuck. I tried running it through a docker-compose as well using ´docker-compose up --build´ with this docker-compose.yml:
services:
  test-client:
    build: .

but it leaves me with:
"Attaching to test-client-1"
after it creates the container itself
It doesn't move onward from there. Any ideas? I can't find any logic behind it running perfectly fine in my local environment, but it quits working as soon as I put it inside a container.
Many thanks!

Is that the output, just Console print, or is there more than that?  (Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.)  You don't seem to have included any ports: in your Compose setup, which means the service won't be accessible from outside Docker, for example from a browser application.

...where is the server running?  Is its code relevant to your issue at all?

The server itself is not relevant to my issue at all, I can reach the WSS server problem free at any given time. Now it just seems like the actual websocket client doesn't get spun up in my docker instance.
This instance does not need to be reached from outside, via ports. It's only purpose will be to listen to a server and recieve messages and handle them..

Are you just hitting Why doesn't Python app print anything when run in a detached docker container?  Do you get more output if you set ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1?  (In the server logs, do you see the connection happening?)  The other thing with the code as you've shown it is that the host name websocket-url is likely to be interpreted as a container name, unless it's a fully-qualified domain name in your actual code.

Wow. That was it. The python unbuffered and the -u flag was the key. Many thanks. Resolved.
